# Move TCPDF-based script to a different folder

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have a script that generates a PDF file using the TCPDF library.

The script works perfectly fine when in its own folder.

I tried moving it to a different folder.

I changed `require_once('pdf_dropbox/tcpdf_include.php');` to refer to the proper location of the include file.

However, I am still getting the `Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in /home/menych/public_html/thetrademarkfactory.ca/invoicepdf.php on line 35` error.

Line 35 has this:
`$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);`

I will be happy to post more code if necessary. I just don't know what parts from which files you need to look at to help.

I would like to keep the library in the separate folder and be able to call the function from ANY page on the server.

Answer (score 7):

Forget `tcpdf_include.php` - that is used in the examples but you don't need it for your production code. Just include `tcpdf.php` instead, ie `require_once('path/to/tcpdf.php');`

Comment: If I change `tcpdf_include.php` to `tcpdf.php`, I am getting errors in the working script: `Warning: opendir(pdf_dropbox/fonts/) [function.opendir]: failed to open dir: No such file or directory in /home/menych/public_html/thetrademarkfactory.ca/pdf_dropbox/tcpdf.php on line 4111
TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: times`
I'm not getting this error with `tcpdf_include`

Comment: Hmmm... you could try setting `K_PATH_MAIN` to the location of your TCPDF installation (pdf_dropbox). Or you can set `K_PATH_FONTS` to pdf_dropbox/fonts - that should definitely fix it. Also, please check that you've still got `tcpdf.php` (hopefully in the pdf_dropbox folder).